# GenericLikelihoodModel to fit binomial distribution: output stderr is nan

Tags: python, statsmodels, mle

Since there are no direct discrete distribution fitting packages in python, I tried to use statsmodels.base.model.GenericLikelihoodModel to fit binomial distribution. However, in some cases, e.g., n=5, p=0.5, every term in the estimation summary is nan except for point estimations.

If I change n from 5 to 10, then everything works well.

My codes are:

```
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.base.model import GenericLikelihoodModel
from scipy.stats import binom


class Binom(GenericLikelihoodModel):
    def loglike(self, params):            
        return np.log(binom.pmf(self.endog, *params)).sum()

n, p = 5, 0.5
params = (n, p)
x = binom.rvs(5, p, size=1000, random_state=1)

res = Binom(x).fit(start_params=params)
res.df_model = len(params)
res.df_resid = len(x) - len(params)
print(res.summary())
```

Related output:

```
        coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
par0  5.0000        nan        nan        nan       nan       nan
par1  0.4972        nan        nan        nan       nan       nan
```

Error messages:

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:23: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/numdiff.py:329: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  - f(*((x - ee[i,:] - ee[j,:],)+args), **kwargs),)

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:875: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:875: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  return (self.a < x) & (x < self.b)

//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py:1814: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  cond2 = cond0 & (x <= self.a)

I finally found the reason why my codes failed. In statsmodels, the calculation of std err is by the formula

```
np.sqrt(np.diag(self.cov_params()))
```

where cov_params is the hessian matrix at the points estimations. In the fitting process, the hessian matrix is calculated by

```
hess[i, j] = (f(*((x + ee[i, :] + ee[j, :],) + args), **kwargs)
                      - f(*((x + ee[i, :] - ee[j, :],) + args), **kwargs)
                      - (f(*((x - ee[i, :] + ee[j, :],) + args), **kwargs)
                      - f(*((x - ee[i, :] - ee[j, :],) + args), **kwargs),)
                      )/(4.*hess[i, j])
```

where f is the loglike function, x are the point estimations and ee are the estimated errors. If the point estimation of n is the real n, then f(n-ee, p) needs to be calculated for hess[i,j]. n-ee < n.

Combined with my customized loglike function, we can see that it involves the calculation of log(0)=Inf (explained below) and the hess[i,j] involves addition of log(0)(leading to nan). That's why the final std err and all the other metrics become nan.

The zero in log(0) is obtained through binom.pmf(x, n, p)=0 where x>n. In my practice, sample size is 1000. Given that binom.pmf(5,5,0.5)=0.03125 and binom.pmf(10,10,0.5)=0.00097, we can see when I choose n=10,p=0.5 for sampling, there may exist no 10 in the sample. Hence we don't encounter log(0) cases. However, if I increase sample size to 1000000, the sample error occur, as expected.

So my question now becomes is there a way, either by modifying my customized loglike function or by overwriting hessian functions in statsmodels, to calculate the std err in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are theoretical and computational problems with Maximum Likelihood estimation when the support of the distribution depends on a parameter.

In this case n defines the upper bound of the distribution, and as far as I remember the inference statistics like standard errors are not valid in this case.

In the usual Binomial case we assume that the number of trials n is known, and we only estimate the probability or proportion. In statsmodels and other packages this can be estimated by using GLM with family Binomial and specifying the number of successes and failures as dependent variable.
By default a Logit link is used which requires that the parameter is transformed to obtain the probability which is done by the predict method in this case.